# influxdb how to assign create/alter retention policy privileges to non-admin users

Tags: influxdb

influxdb 
is it possible to assign create/alter retention policy privileges to non-admin users

Currently non-admin user have ALL privileges to a test db.
But when tried to create/alter retention policy on test db, throws an error with "requires admin privilege"

influxdb version - 1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** Is it possible to assign create/alter retention policy privileges to non-admin users

**A:** Short answer: **No.**

In `influxdb` version 1.1.x, even now (1.3.1), only `administrators` can perform `administrative queries` to;

1. Create or drop database
2. Drop series or drop measurements
3. **Create, alter or drop retention policy**
4. Create or drop continuous query.

A normal `user` can only hold `Read`, `Write` or `BOTH (ALL)` privileges for databases. "Database privilege" only allows user to go about changing/reading point data for a `measurement`, nothing more.